# Inserting into a 2-3 Tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

I'm not sure if I am understanding the insertion process of a 2-3 Tree correctly. Say I have the tree:

[image: Original Tree]

and I want to insert the value 95 into it, would this be the proper new tree?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct.

Inserting 95 would place 3 children in the rightmost leaf (not allowed)

```
        40 
      /    \
    20     60, 80
   / \     /   | \
 10  30   50  70 90,95,100 <- not valid
```

The 3 nodes in the leaf make 95 move to the parent node, but now there are 3 nodes in the parent:

```
        40 
      /    \
    20      60,80,95 <- not valid
   /  \     /   |  \
  10  30   50  70 90,100
```

Moving 95 up causes the parent node to split:

```
        40 
      /    \
    20       80
   /  \    /    \
  10  30  60     95
          / \   /  \
        50  70 90  100 valid
```

Answer (score 0):

this is incorrect. the height of 2-3 tree is consistent hence you will split the parent not the child.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong. You are violating one fact about 2-3 tree: all leaves have same depth.
reference:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/10.23TREE.html#operations

Here is trace of insertion I have in mind:

[image]

Please let me know if this is incorrect.